Is there way to access the URL the button will redirect to ifs decided by site JS code
I'm trying to scrape a website for product detail. So it has many buttons, for instance of below code.
<button aria-label="ARIA_LABEL_NAME" class="CLASS_NAME"><span class="CLASS_NAME"><img src="SRC_REMOVED" alt="" class="e-1yuw6bt"></span></button>

Now when I click above button on the site, it dynamically loads the product details and the source site(from where I original clicked the button) state is lost.
There are some other buttons of other products too but those when clicked just change the URL of the source site and then opens a popup without dynamically loading the new site (by replacing its complete HTML content with source site).
Now the thing is that for me the URL is of usefulness as it contains SKU which I can not find elsewhere.
I tried many solutions but none works for instance preventing propagation of that button event(result: clicking any button or this button will do nothing).
The above implementation is part of Chrome Extension Manifest V3.
What I am looking for
I would like to know if there is way to access what the button will redirect to without loading the content or somehow see the source code (which I tried but seems like its minified) that how this button JS code works so I can have some clue or some other solution.
Thanks!

It depends on what API the button uses. If it's location then no, it's unforgeable, but if it's history.pushState then you can spoof it in the MAIN world.

@wOxxOm So far I can see it is calling a function but checking source of that function its minified version. So how to deal with it in this scenario?

Debug it in devtools or use search.

@wOxxOm Issue is that, as soon as the button is clicked, it changes URL and immediately loads new content(dynamically) so is there way to not allow the content to be loaded, just the URL is changed? I really do not want to lose the original source site or the operations I was doing there.

Like I said, use devtools to debug the code that runs when the button is clicked. You can find it in the Event listeners panel in the Elements tab.

@wOxxOm ok thanks alot, I did followed that and found out that it is using react states to build up that URL. From console, I can see that react properties as part of "scopes" that is with event listener of onClick. Now how I can access that from the console?
Right now, I'm doing something this
Object.values(document.querySelectorAll(".e-1rsbmf7")[5])[1]
Index 1, will retrieve this object of onClick that has "Scopes" and then Closure properties and in one of the Closure it has that key property containing SKU but I can only see that and not able to retrieve the key as its within [[Scopes]]

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
